# How to viewthe actual command executed by "subprocess.check_call()"

Tags: python, command-line

I have a command as given below

```
subprocess.check_call(["C:\\Program Files\\operation.exe", "execute", "-af", "createrecord.xml", " -stuName", student,"-gender" ,gender], shell=True)
```

When I run this command manually it works fine. I believe that the subprocess.check_call() has not parsed the command properly (probably my mistake). How to view the output of subprocess.check_call().
    I'd like to see the acutal command with arguments as called by subprocess.check_call()

NOTE - I don't want to see the return value of the command's execution. I only what to see how the command has been formatted by subprocess.check_call()

Comment: In the code, (a) there is an extra space in front of `-stuname` and (b) there appears to be a comma missing between `"-gender"` and `gender`.

Comment: Are you getting any exception? If so, add the exception stack trace also.

Comment: Hi that must've been a typo. But assume the command works. How do I print the command subprocess.check_call() is actually executing ? The command is purely an example :)

Comment: You could improve the command by using a raw string, as in r"C:\Program Files\operation.exe"

Comment: @GreenAsJade A single backslash is treated as the escape character by Python, so using regular strings in Windows is very error prone when typing paths. Using 'raw' Python strings avoids this issue.

Comment: have you tried concatenating all parameters in a single string?

Comment: @Eric, coincidentally I too thought of that just now. I think join() would help in this case. Thanks

Comment: I did some experimentation with the concept of `check_call(['echo'] + ['testcommand.exe', 'arg'] + ['>output.txt'], shell=True)` and encountered `Wierd Shit(TM)`.   Under Windows, `check_call(["ls", "-l"], shell=True)` produces different effect than `check_call("ls -l", shell=True)`, and different again without `shell=True` and different again under Linux.   FWIW...  (I found the documentation totally opaque on this topic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the list form of the `subprocess` stuff only with (possibly implicit) `shell=False` and the string form only with `shell=True`.

The shell can only work with a command line which it then parses on its own. Without the shell, `exec*()` functions are usedm, which take the command line arguments in a separated way.

For Windows, this only holds up to a certain level, but it remains valid.