# Show in terminal commad executed by subprocess.check_call() in python

Tags: python, subprocess

A similar question has been asked and answered here: [How to viewthe actual command executed by "subprocess.check_call()"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26859291/how-to-viewthe-actual-command-executed-by-subprocess-check-call)

I tried the `shell=True` option, but it shows the command including all the commas and braces. I would like to command to appear clean, as it would be executed in terminal.

One option is using `print()`, but is there an option to avoid being redundant. I don't want to have the same piece of code written many times in my script. (Yeah I know, declaring the command as a variable is possible too, what else?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are passing the arguments as a list to subprocess, so printing the command is usually just a simple call to `delimiter.join(list)`.

```
params = ["my.exe", "-param1", "-param2", "value 2"]
if debug:
  print("executed command: " + " ".join(params))
result = subprocess.check_call(params)
```

Note: This does not add the propper quote signs needed to copy&paste the printed string into a shell like PowerShell or Bash.